# for Xamarin Forms, is there a REST API for queries, or do I have to create endpoints?

Tags: sql, rest, xamarin.forms

I would like to connect a Xamarin Forms app to a cloud DB and submit queries (or updates, etc) to the DB via some sort of REST API, where the info passed to the DB is a query, not and endpoint.

I'm seeing plenty of documentation on using various packages to communicate via endpoints, which means I would have to setup those endpoints on my cloud DB. But I don't see anything on using freeform queries.

I realize that in the long run, free form queries are not going to be as efficient. But they would sure make dev & debugging easier. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: it depends on what database you're using.  "cloud db" is pretty vague.  Some will have client libraries you can use, some allow direct SQL connections, others will require you to setup your own endpoints.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "direct SQL". I still want to do a REST ful query, where the query is sent as a "GET", not something that maintains a connection and then works through that.  As for a DB, I was looking at MariaDB because I have that via CPanel on one of my servers, but it doesn't have to be MariaDB.

Comment: Googling “mariadb rest api” returns interesting results.  But there is really no answer for this question.  It depends on your db.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at the docs for creating MariaDB endpoints. That's probably what I'll end up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Which cloud service are you using? If it's AWS, check out Lambda. In Azure, Azure Functions is Equivalent. You can use that to create a serverless endpoint.

Comment: My question might not be clear. I want a DB server but I was trying to avoid writing an end point for each CRUD action and instead have one endpoint that handles any SQL from the client. I have abandoned that approach, since it brings in too many problems.

Comment: I got it. If you don't want to create an endpoint, try mysqlconnector [link](https://mysqlconnector.net/). it also supports mariadb.